# Working with functions in angular js factories

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I am getting a value from rest api in a factory, resolving its promise in the controller and then again I want to send the previously retrieved data in the controller using $http from the factory. Have a look at the code, The problem i am coming through is that upon executing this, the second async function doesn't works. Am i doing anything wrong here? Also is it a good practice to pass data like that in Json i.e. pass a function?

[Screenshot of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQCSH.png)

```
app.factory('PatientSummaryFactory2', function(\$http){
var patient = "${ patient.uuid }";
var url1 = "/" + OPENMRS_CONTEXT_PATH + "/ws/rest/v1/encounter";
var date2 = new Date();
return {
 getdata: function(){
    var providerUrl = "/" + OPENMRS_CONTEXT_PATH + "/ws/rest/v1/session";
    return \$http.get(providerUrl).then(function(response){
    return response.data.user.uuid;  // PASS THIS DATA INTO JSON TO POST
  });
 }
};

var json = {
  patient: patient,
  encounterType: window.constantConfigObj.encounterTypeVisitNote,
  encounterProviders: [{
   provider: getdata(),  //IS THIS A GOOD PRACTICE?
   encounterRole: "73bbb069-9781-4afc-a9d1-54b6b2270e03"
 }],
  visit: visitId,
  encounterDatetime: date2
};
console.log(json);
return {
async: function(){
  return \$http.post(url1, JSON.stringify(json)).then(function(response){
    return response.data.uuid;
   });
  }
 };
});

app.controller('PatientSummaryController', function(\$scope, \$http, 
PatientSummaryFactory1, PatientSummaryFactory2, recentVisitFactory) {
PatientSummaryFactory2.getdata().then(function(response){
    console.log(response);   //RESOLVING THE PROMISE
});
\$scope.isLoading = true;
\$scope.visitEncounters = [];
\$scope.visitObs = [];
\$scope.visitNoteData = [];
\$scope.visitStatus = false;
 recentVisitFactory.fetchVisitDetails(visitId).then(function(data) {
                    \$scope.visitDetails = data.data;
                    \$scope.visitEncounters = data.data.encounters;
                    if(\$scope.visitEncounters.length !== 0) {
                        angular.forEach(\$scope.visitEncounters, 
  function(value, key){
                            var encounter = value.display;
                            if(encounter.match("Visit Note") !== null) {
                                var encounterUuid = value.uuid;
                                visitNoteEncounterUuid = encounterUuid;
                                isVisitNotePresent = true;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    if (isVisitNotePresent == false || 
                    \$scope.visitEncounters.length == 0) {

                    PatientSummaryFactory2.async().then(function(d2){ 
                                    \$scope.data2 = d2;
                                    visitNoteEncounterUuid = d2;
                      console.log(\$scope.data2);
                                }); 

                    }
                }, function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
            });
```

Comment: you shouldn't have 2 `return` calls. Merge them or create an object of functions first and return it (`var service = {};`, `service.async = function(...){...}`, `return service;`)

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could just give me a more in depth answer using an example or may be using my code, thanks

Comment: merge your factory functions into one return call: `return {getdata : function(){...}, async : function(){...}};`

Comment: Ok, and what changes to make in controller? I hope you understood the scenario. i want to pass the get data() returned value to scope.json which is in the factory itself and then async function executes

Answer (score 0):

You can't have several (2 in your case) `return` calls. Your error indicates that `async` is not a function because it **return**ed `getdata` previously and will not consider any other functions to be returned separately.

You have multiple variations on how to resolve this issue:

#### Merge functions in one `return`

```
return {
  getdata: function(){
    ...
  },
  async: function(){
    ...
  }
};
```

Or:

```
function getdata(){...}
function async(){...}
return {
  getdata: getdata,
  async: async
};
```

#### Return an object of functions

```
var service = {
  getdata: function(){...},
  async: function(){...}
};
return service;
```

Or:

```
var service = {};
service.getdata = function(){...}
service.async = function(){...}
return service;
```

Or:

```
function getdata(){...}
function async(){...}
var service = {
  getdata: getdata,
  async: async
};
return service;
```

Comment: Ok i get that, but will the getdata() value be resolved in the json in that case?